Missing Power Option in control panel & Settings | Help Me
After watching some video I decided to use Auto Cpufreq https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/auto-cpufreq.git .
It not working as i want , so after removing this , the power mode disappeared , then i installed power-profiles-daemon , it also not working on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS .
System : AMD Ryzen 5 5500u
Laptop : HP 14s .
Missing Power Mode in Settings Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
please if anyone have any suggestion for me please share .
also suugest me something for long battery life for my Laptop .
Also Missing From Control Center Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
